# Is it possible to dynamically render text boxes in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, office-interop

I'm trying to build a WPF app that previews and modifies a .docx document. It modifies it by replacing keywords with user input.

The keywords are $keyword1$ * 14 and $keyword2$ * 10, etc.

While my app is showing the contents of the .docx document, including the keywords, I would like them (the keywords) to be covered by a rendered text box on the exact position inside the preview pane. These text boxes would act like input to replace the keyword that is covering/overlaying. I hope it's clear enough.

**My question is the following: Is it possible to dynamically render text boxes that position themselves over the keyword? If yes, where should I look about this?**

The code below is for .Net WinForms and uses Office Interop to preview the word document in a richtextbox. I'm currently trying to make it work in WPF. Since Microsoft says that Office Interop is unstable and unsupported, I'm considering trying OpenXML to get the same results.

Thanks for reading this and apologies for the silly question. I'm at the beginning of my coding career.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace wordtoform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly object fnd;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                object filename = @"D:\test.docx";
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application AC = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
                object readOnly = true;
                object isVisible = true;
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                try
                {
                    doc = AC.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible);
                    doc.Content.Select();
                    doc.Content.Copy();
                    richTextBox1.Paste();

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: "Microsoft says that Office Interop is unstable and unsupported" Can you give me a reference for this statement?

Comment: Why are there several variables object?

Comment: You can [`Inline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.inline?view=netframework-4.8) a `TextBox` for each keyword directly into to the `FlowDocument` of the `RichTextBox` using the [`InlineUIContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer?view=netframework-4.8#examples).

Comment: For performance reasons it might be more convenient to create as hotkey that allows the editing user to jump between the keywords. You then select the currently navigated keyword, so that the user can instantly replace them by typing. Adding a `TextBox` for each keyword could perform very bad, depending on their count.

Comment: @Mary "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: @BionicCode Thank you Bionic, I might go for the hotkey solution.

Comment: But this does not appear to be unattended or non-interactive.